# How to set a namespace prefix to a payload xsl

Tags: xslt, xpath, namespaces, prefix

I have this payload, what I am intresting to know is how i can add this "TV:" namespace prefix to all nodes and elementes in it.

```
<TVInqResponse>
         <TVInqRS>
            <StatusCode>0</StatusCode>
            <StatusDescription>Success</StatusDescription>

This is what is expect to have as a result:

<**tv**:TVInqResponse>
         <**tv**:TVInqRS>
            <**tv**:StatusCode>0</**tv**:StatusCode>
            <**tv**:StatusDescription>Success</**tv**:StatusDescription>
```

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:tv="some:tv">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="tv:{name()}" namespace="some:tv">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (based on the malformed provided "playload"...):

```
<TVInqResponse>
 <TVInqRS>
  <StatusCode>0</StatusCode>
  <StatusDescription>Success</StatusDescription>
 </TVInqRS>
</TVInqResponse>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<tv:TVInqResponse xmlns:tv="some:tv">
   <tv:TVInqRS>
      <tv:StatusCode>0</tv:StatusCode>
      <tv:StatusDescription>Success</tv:StatusDescription>
   </tv:TVInqRS>
</tv:TVInqResponse>
```

**If you also want any attribute name to be in the same namespace, replace the template matching attributes with this one**:

```
 <xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:attribute name="tv:{name()}" namespace="some:tv">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
```